# Why is there much difference in query plan with union vs "or" operator

Tags: postgresql, query-planner

While executing below two queries, I notice serious difference in query plan. Why is that?

```
select * from table1
where id = 'dummy' or id in (select id from table2 where id = 'dummy')
```

Query plan

```
Seq Scan on table1  (cost=8.30..49611.63 rows=254478 width=820) (actual time=535.477..557.431 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (((code)::text = 'dummy'::text) OR (hashed SubPlan 1))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 510467
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Index Scan using idx on table2  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
          Index Cond: ((id)::text = 'dummy'::text)
Planning Time: 0.165 ms
Execution Time: 557.517 ms
```

```
select * from table1
where id = 'dummy' 
union 
select * from table1
where id in (select id from table2 where id = 'dummy')
```

```
Unique  (cost=25.22..25.42 rows=2 width=5818) (actual time=0.045..0.047 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=25.22..25.23 rows=2 width=5818) (actual time=0.045..0.046 rows=1 loops=1)
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Append  (cost=0.42..25.21 rows=2 width=5818) (actual time=0.016..0.026 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using id on table1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=820) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((id)::text = 'dummy'::text)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..16.74 rows=1 width=820) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using idx on table2  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((id)::text = 'dummy'::text)
                    ->  Index Scan using pkey on table1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=820) (never executed)
                          Index Cond: (id = table2.id)
Planning Time: 0.753 ms
Execution Time: 0.131 ms
```

So the main difference you can see is the first query returns 254478 rows but the second just returns 2 rows.
Why is that?

Comment: Union does a `distinct` on the data result;  unless you use `UNION ALL`  OR will return every record including duplicates

Comment: @xQbert but why does the first query returns 200,000 rows? How does psql internally run ```where id = 'dummy' or id in (select id from table2 where id = 'dummy')```

Comment: `mysql`<>`postgresql`

Comment: add UNION ALL to your union statement do you get the same count?  or add DISTINCT to your first query do you get 2 records?  First I want to make sure the results are in fact the same

Comment: @xQbert Still returns 2 rows with union all.

Comment: @Springbootprogammer I understand your confusion now.    The result of the subquery is an ID that equals 'dummy' you're already searching for dummy.  there are only 2 records with dummy in table 1 as it's Id.  so why is or seemingly resulting in a Cartesian product between table1 and table 2?  Yeah I'd need a example set of data on a dbfiddle and prove this out on ... whatever engine this is...  I can't see how the SQL would do this

Comment: yes @xQbert . How does psql internally run the ```condition OR (subplan)```

Comment: my understanding is it materializes a list of the ID's = 'dummy' so it would return ('dummy','dummy','dummy') if you had 3 in table2.  Then each record in table 1 is checked agasint 2 conditions id = dummy or ID in ('dummy','dummy',dummy')  So this results is quite odd... i'd love to see sample data and it recreated on a dbfiddle

Comment: That is not how optimization on SQL works -- you can't ask how `condition OR (subplan)` works because what isi n the condition or what is in the subplan will change the whole plan

Comment: you have both mysql and postgresql in your tags it can't be both so I deleted them.  Let us know when you figure out what system you are using.

Comment: @Hogan Edited the tags, thought the query plan are mostly same in all system so sql guys might help

Comment: No they are different on every system.  If you want all "sql guys" then you can use the SQL tag or ansi-sql tag.   But in most cases you are going to get better answers if you tag the platform you are using.

Comment: @Springbootprogammer in actually depending upon indexes and data volume the exact same query can generate a different execution plan in the same database on the same RDBMS on different runs.

Comment: are you able to recreate this situation on a dbfiddle somewhere?   Like: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14 for example?

Comment: @Springbootprogammer I'm not able to recreate your scenairo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d2e5b9239aa25b09b715b9129cd46e2d  which makes me believe it's environmental and not SQL related... what version of postgresql?

Comment: They both return 1 row.  254478 is an *estimate*, apparently a very bad one.

Answer (score 4):

Please do another test -- run both these queries -- do they give the same results as the queries without my changes?

```
 select * from table1
 where table1.id = 'dummy' or 
       table1.id in (select table2.id from table2 where table2.id = 'dummy')


 select * from table1
 where table1.id = 'dummy' 
 union 
 select * from table1
 where table1.id in (select table2.id from table2 where table2.id = 'dummy')
```

I don't think you are sharing your actual code with us -- because as written your code makes little sense -- you are returning a list of ids in the sub-query that equal 'dummy' -- so you will just get a list of dummy multiple times.

---

*Note these comments are not true since they had no impact on the results -- the order of operations was working as expected*

What result do you get when when you do this:

```
select * from table1
where (id = 'dummy') or id in (select id from table2 where id = 'dummy')
```

The reason your query was giving more results is because it was selecting records from table1 where id equals dummy or id = id.  The query in the original post gives you all the records.  The OR was being applied to the first expression not splitting two expressions.

Comment: The same result as the second query.

Comment: There you go -- now you know why

Comment: I gotta admit this surprises me.

Comment: @xQbert :)  -- I went on a hunch.

Comment: Hi @Hogan could you please add a bit of explanation to your answer? I was about to flag it as it is not an answer rather a comment until I had to head the whole comments section. Thank you!

Comment: Better! Thank you! \o/

Comment: @Hogan Please add some more explanation, what would be when the query is `where id = 'dummy' or id = 'dummy'` will it return all rows? I think no, so why would `or in` return all if you have a `where` clause in subquery.

Comment: @shmiel -- no the query is `where id = 'dummy' or id` and then it ignores the rest of the sql for the result set

Comment: @Hogan  The  query ```select id from table2 where id = 'dummy'```  in first query runs first and if doesn't return any record, how will it return all the records then?  Thanks for answer though

Comment: Aha it's a `and` `or` problem. WOW.

Comment: @Springbootprogammer -- the query is returning the same results as `select id from table2 where id = id` because of the OR

Comment: @Shmiel -- NO it is an order of operations problem -- it adds in ID as one of the thing that ID can be equal to.

Comment: @Hogan so Correct me if I m wrong, so the ```(select id from table2 where id = 'dummy')``` in first query runs every time the for ```table1.id != 'dummy '```

Comment: can't say for sure -- most engines would not do that unless there was a correlated field (which you don't have here)  -- most engines would just run the sub-query once and use the results later.

Comment: @Hogan the query in the answer returns same result as first query, not second query. Sorry about this misunderstanding. I checked again. Does it affect the answer?

Comment: yes --  @Springbootprogammer that means this was not the problem

Comment: @Hogan really sorry about this misunderstanding.

Comment: @Hogan Yes they give exactly same result as queries in question.